# Angularjs image upload without using php in offline mode

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have tried to move the uploaded file to local folder using javascript and angularjs. But its not working. Is it possible to move the canvas image to folder without using php? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please include what you've tried so far and what error you get in your question.

Comment: When asking a question about a problem caused by your code, you will get much better answers if you provide code people can use to reproduce the problem. See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).